# Create 2-D array of strings with nested fill

Tags: arrays, string, julia

I am initializing a vector of strings like this

```
mask = fill(fill(' ', maxx), maxy)
```

in order to then populate it by setting individual elements:

```
mask[y][x] = '·'
```

This doesn't work: I get `maxy` times the same string. I guess the outer `fill` just creates a list of pointers to the `Vector` created by the inner `fill` (the [documentation of `fill!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.fill!) confirms this explicitly). What should I do instead?

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use a list comprehension like this:

```
mask = [fill(' ', maxx) for y in 1:maxy]
```

(But I'd still be interested to learn whether there is a solution with `fill`.)

Comment: Seems unlikely (a solution with `fill`), since part of the documentation for `fill` itself says "If x is an object reference, all elements will refer to the same object", with no further lines on exceptions to that or options to change that.

Comment: I see, thanks! Then at least I didn't miss anything obvious.